Should I be concerned about possible mold on/near my window ac unit?
https://imgur.com/a/EQEQnQq
Hi all, I’m moving into this historic house and see this around the ac unit. I don’t notice mold anywhere else. Does possible mold around the ac indicate a mold problem in the home or just poor sealing of the window unit? I’m in florida where it is quite humid outside.

In Florida it's easy for things to get some mold or mildew as you know.
From the picture, it looks like a minor amount, if it is mold. It very well can be crumbs from the black foam sealing strip.  Either way, there is nothing showing there that indicates a mold problem.
